# Convert timezone into other timezone php

Tags: php, timezone

I have no clue how to ask this question other than saying, I have a time zone "America/Boise" and I want to use php to convert it from "America/Boise" to get a more broad timezone such as "US/Mountain". How would I do this?

Comment: Look at the [PHP DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and the [DateTimezone class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

Comment: The best I can get from your suggestions is: Array
(
    [country_code] => US
    [latitude] => 43.61361
    [longitude] => -116.2025
    [comments] => Mountain Time - south Idaho & east Oregon
), I need US/Mountain

Comment: `Mountain .......... America/Denver`

Comment: Huh? I know it says "Mountain Time - south Idaho & east Oregon", I need US/Mountain it really does make a difference, too many potential issues if it doesn't

Comment: [get composer](https://getcomposer.org/) `composer require nesbot/carbon` carbon solves all time related problems, and [is well documented](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: Are you looking for a way to convert the time itself or the string ("America/Boise")?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really achieve this without comparing all of the intricacies of each of the two time zones.  They really are different entries:

- `US/Mountain` is an alias for `America/Denver`, and the latter form is preferred actually.  It is representative of the majority of the Mountain Time zone in the United States.
- `America/Boise` is specifically to cover a region in Southern Idaho that deviated from what we now consider to be "Mountain Time" at several points in the past.  The last deviation was in 1974, when DST started later in Idaho that year.  You can review the differences in [the `northamerica` file in the tzdb sources](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/northamerica), or by using a site like timeanddate.com to compare [Boise](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/boise) and [Denver](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/denver).

Considering the differences, the only way you could objectively map the Boise zone to the rest of Mountain Time is if you decided on a minimum threshold date.  Any deviations before that date would be considered inconsequential to distinguish between the two zones.

Then you just have the problem of figuring out which one to pick.  On a case-by-case basis, this may seem trivial.  But if you consider all the time zones of the world, sometimes you just don't have enough information to be selective, and will need to have some sort of tiebreaker data, such as population statistics, or just a preference/rank-order list, to decide which to use.

Sorry for not being able to provide simple code, but it's not a simple problem.  If you're interested, I've got a demo of some .NET code that implements some of this work for the purposes of building a time zone picker that minimizes the number of entries.  The [live demo is here](http://timezonepickerdemo.azurewebsites.net/), and [the source code is here](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames/tree/master/Demos/TimeZonePickerDemo).  Sorry, I don't have anything similar for PHP, but you may be able to extrapolate.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you.

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2016-08-22 12:00:00', new DateTimeZone('America/Boise'));
echo $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s').PHP_EOL;

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('MST'));
echo $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
```

Results:

```
08/22/2016 12:00:00
08/22/2016 11:00:00
```